# how to escape metacharacter like "/" and "." in regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Original:

```
src="this/text/is/not/needed/me/at/all/<filename>.jpg"
src="this/is/another/text/that/is//also/not/required/<filename>.jpg"
```

My desired output should be:

```
src="IMAGES/<filename>.jpg"
```

I want to remove the path of `*.jpg` file in `src="`" and want `src="images/*.jpg"` using regex in notepad++.

How can I do that?

Comment: I found the answer googling the exact title of your question.

Comment: `/` isn't a metacharacter, `.` can be escaped as `\.` or `[.]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Find what: src=".*/(.*\.jpg)"
Replace with: src="images/$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace `src=".*?\/([^\/]*?\.jpg)"` with `src="images/$1"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to find -

```
(src=").*(\/.*\..*")
```

And replace with -

```
$1IMAGES$2
```

A single REPLACE ALL should work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `src=".*/([^/]+.jpg)"` with `src="images/$1"`